# Software similar to Stack Exchange

Tags: web-apps

This question is different from the one I asked previously ([Similar software to Stack Exchange, but with flavor of support group](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/45198/similar-software-to-stack-exchange-but-with-flavor-of-support-group)).  That one was focused more on support group functioning and less on unique, upvoted and accepted answers.

An existing forum needs to migrate to a different type of software.  I would like it to be similar in many ways, in its functioning, to Stack Exchange.

What software could be used to accomplish this?

**Clarification:**

- SE: I like the tags method of organization, the editing, the clean look, the voting; searching works great.
- Why I can't use SE: the group would prefer to be self-governing.

Price: I'm willing to consider anything but free would be preferable.  Self-hosting is an option.

Comment: So you need a self-hosted SE, is that right? And you are aware of the fact that this isn't a forum software (though it could possibly be used as such, in a way)? Forums are rather discussions, while SE sites are rather Q&As.

Comment: @izzy - Yes.  "Forum" might not have been the right description.  At any rate, I am used to SE and would be happy to find something similar.

Comment: Then it should fit, good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote a good answer, that you can see [there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/are-there-any-clones-alternatives-for-running-a-stack-exchange-style-qa-site), you can see the community already raised a hand to see if similar software exist.

---

> Stack Exchange has released an updated, feature-complete version of
>   the Stack Overflow engine which is now available for enterprise use. 
>   You can read more about that here
>
> [**The Stack Exchange engine is available for
>   use**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197549/98786)
>
> (Note that this is different from [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams), which
>   is a hosted solution.)
>
> But if that does not meet your needs, there are several third-party
>   tools that try to clone at least some of the functionality here.
>
> **Most active that look like the best bets**
>
> ***Open source***
>
> - **[ASKBOT](http://askbot.org/en/questions/)**: Python/Django. [Hosting](http://askbot.com), [code](http://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel), [docs](http://askbot.org/doc/index.html),
>     [import](http://askbot.org/doc/import-data.html). GPLv3
> - **[Biostars](https://github.com/ialbert/biostar-central)**: [Demo](https://biostars.org). Python, Django. MIT license
> - **[Django-knowledge](https://github.com/zapier/django-knowledge)**: [Demo](http://django-knowledge.org/). (July 10, 2019: Repo is
>     read-only) Python, Django. ISC license
> - **[LampCMS](http://www.lampcms.com)**: [Demo](http://support.lampcms.com/) (June 13, 2019: Demo sites do not
>     work). PHP 5.3, MongoDB. LGPL3
> - **[Mamute](http://www.mamute.org/)**: [Demo 1](http://demo.mamute.org/), [Demo 2](http://meta.mamute.org/) (June 11, 2017: Demo
>     sites do not work). Java. Customizable. Apache 2 license
> - **[PaizaQA](https://github.com/gi-no/paizaqa)**: [Demo](http://paizaqa.herokuapp.com), MEAN (MongoDB, Express, AngularJS,
>     and Node.js), MIT license
> - **[Kliqqi](https://github.com/Kliqqi-CMS/Kliqqi-CMS/)**: PHP, MySQL. Different look, hosting. Not active,
>     CC-BY 3.0 license
> - **[Question2Answer](http://www.question2answer.org/)**: [Demo](http://www.question2answer.org/qa/). PHP, MySQL. [Fairly
>     active](https://github.com/q2a/question2answer). GPLv2+
> - **[Scoold](https://scoold.com/)**: [Demo](https://live.scoold.com/), Java, active since Jan. 2017, Apache
>     2 license
> - **[Talkyard](https://www.talkyard.io)**: [Demo](https://www.talkyard.io/forum/latest). React.js, Scala. Also has
>     open-ended discussions & chat. [Hosting](https://www.talkyard.io/pricing), [code](https://github.com/debiki/talkyard),
>     [installation](https://github.com/debiki/talkyard-prod-one). AGPL.
> - **[Vanilla Forums](https://vanillaforums.com/en/features/qna/)**: [Demo](https://open.vanillaforums.com/discussions/unanswered). PHP, MySQL. Forums with [Q&A
>     config option](http://docs.vanillaforums.com/help/addons/qna/). [Active](https://github.com/vanilla/vanilla) and has [Commercial and Open
>     Source](https://vanillaforums.com/en/software/) plans. GPLv2
>
> ***Not open source***
>
> - **[AllAnswered](https://www.allanswered.com)**: Django. Include Q&A in its knowledge
>     management system. Not Free.
> - **[AnswerHub](http://www.dzonesoftware.com/products/answerhub-question-answer-software)**: Java. [Live site](http://community.dzonesoftware.com/). Enterprise Q&A by the
>     people who created [OSQA](http://www.dzonesoftware.com/products/open-source-question-answer-software). Not free.
> - **[Confluence Questions](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/questions)**: Java. Enterprise Q&A developed and
>     supported by [Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/). Not free.
> - **[Haydle](http://haydle.com/)**: SaaS, free 30 day trial.  Haydle is focused on
>     being a private, internal Q&A system.
> - **[Q&A](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/qa-wordpress-questions-and-answers-plugin/)**: [<s>Live Site</s>](http://wpmu.org/questions/). WordPress Plugin. Actively
>     developed by a company that looks reliable. No longer free; $19 to
>     download (with no membership)
> - **[Quandora](http://www.quandora.com)**
> - **[Rootbuzz](https://www.rootbuzz.com/)**: Django, hosting, actively developed, non-free
> - **[SabaiDiscuss](http://sabaidiscuss.com/)**: commercial WordPress Plugin
> - **[Programlama](https://programlama.tk)**: Python, flask (In Turkish)
> - **[Unity Answers](https://answers.unity.com)**: Allowed topics are the Unity editor and C#
>     (the site is free and in English)
>
> **Ones that look sort of finished**
>
> - **[shapado](https://github.com/ricodigo/shapado)**: Ruby, mongomapper and MongoDB. AGPLv3. Website
>     unreachable, Last commit in 2012.
> - **[OSQA](https://github.com/dzone/osqa)**: Django. GPLv3. Last commit in 2015. [AnswerHub](http://dzonesoftware.com/)
>     has replaced OSQA as DZone's primary Q&A solution.
> - **[openoverflow](https://github.com/nsanta/openoverflow)**: Ruby, PostgreSQL, Haml. MIT license. No
>     example site, and I can't find anyone using this one. Not a lot of
>     recent activity; last code commit, May 2009.
> - **[phpancake](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpancake/)**: PHP, Zend framework, MySQL. [Live site](http://phpancake.sourceforge.net/).
>     MIT license. Last activity Jan 2013. Renders very poorly in some
>     browsers; the live site states "I am aware of this site not working
>     properly. I am working on it!".
> - **[cahoots](http://cahoots.sourceforge.net/)**: PHP, MySQL. GPL, MIT license. Officially
>     inactive; demo site offline; last update Aug 2010.
> - **[Coordino](http://coordino.com/)**: PHP, MySQL. MIT license. [feature
>     tour](http://coordino.com/tour); last commit in 2015.
> - **[Qwench](https://github.com/anantgarg/Qwench)**: PHP. [Example site](http://anantgarg.com/qwench) (currently offline).
>     [Almost no activity since 2009](https://github.com/anantgarg/Qwench/commits/master).
> - **[soclone](https://code.google.com/p/soclone/)**: Django framework. MIT license. Seems to have
>     [gone stale in Nov 2008](https://code.google.com/p/soclone/source/list) (and only started on Google Code at the
>     end of Oct 2008).
> - **[Solace](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/solace)**: Inactive; last commit in 2010.
> - **[Kliqqi](https://github.com/Kliqqi-CMS/Kliqqi-CMS/)**: PHP, MySQL. Different look, hosting available.
>     Not active, CC-BY 3.0 license
> - **[stacked](https://code.google.com/p/stacked/)**: ASP.NET, Ra-Ajax, ActiveRecord ORM. GPLv3.
> - **[Arrayshift](http://drupal.org/project/arrayshift)** Drupal plugin GPLv2, last commit in 2016.
> - **[Kunjika](https://github.com/shivshankardayal/Kunjika)**: Python, Flask, and Couchbase. GNU GPLv3 or
>     later. [Website](http://10hash.com/) (not reachable anymore as of October 2019).
>
> **Others that seem to be work in progress**
>
> - **[Asking](https://github.com/Bivee/asking)**: Perl, Mojolicious.
>     Perl License (Artistic). Little documentation at this point. GitHub
>     repository README.md in Portuguese.
> - **[FortyTwo](https://github.com/mcaprari/fortytwo/)**: Python, Django, CouchDB. [Example site](http://couch.caprazzi.net/fortytwo/_design/fortytwo/index.html)
>     *link leads to a 404*. Unknown license. Little information. [Last commit in January 2011]
> - **[kerjakelompok](https://github.com/fuadmuhammad/kerjakelompok/)**: No example site. Unknown license. Little
>     info.
> - **[SmartR](https://github.com/dkd/smartr/)**: No example site. MIT License. Little info.
> - **[Stack Underflow](https://github.com/ripper234/Stack-Underflow/)**: C#. No example site. License is "do
>     whatever you want with it" (I haven't defined a formal license yet).
>     Written as a learning project.
> - **[T002_rails-overflow](https://github.com/membrain/T002_rails-overflow/)**: Ruby on Rails. No example site.
>     Unknown license. Little info. Apache license.
> - <s>**[CNPROG](https://github.com/cnprog/CNPROG)**: Python/Django.</s> Project officially
>     closed. Was used as base by OSQA & Askbot.
> - **[QARoR](http://github.com/mateuszdw/qaror)** - open source
>     questions & answers platform for Ruby on Rails. Here is the
>     [demo](http://qaror.herokuapp.com) and source on
>     [GitHub](http://github.com/mateuszdw/qaror). Released under MIT
>     License.
>
> ### Sorted by language
>
> **PHP**
>
> - **[Question2Answer](http://www.question2answer.org/)**  * **[cahoots](http://cahoots.sourceforge.net/)**  *
>     **[phpancake](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpancake/)**  * **[LampCMS](http://www.lampcms.com)**  * **[Coordino](http://coordino.com/)**  * **[Q&A](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/qa-wordpress-questions-and-answers-plugin/)** (Is a WordPress Plugin)  * **Arrayshift**  * **[Vanilla Forums](https://vanillaforums.com/en/features/qna/)**
>
> **Perl**
>
> - **[Asking](https://github.com/Bivee/asking)**
>
> **Python**
>
> - **[ASKBOT](http://askbot.org/en/questions/)**  * **[Biostars](https://github.com/ialbert/biostar-central)**  * **[FortyTwo](https://github.com/mcaprari/fortytwo/)**  *
>     **[Kunjika](https://10hash.com)**  * **[OSQA](https://github.com/OSQA/osqa/)** ([merged](http://dzonesoftware.com/qa/questions/40767/a-much-needed-upgrade-for-metaosqanet.html) to AnswerHub)  * **[soclone](https://code.google.com/p/soclone/)**  * **[Rootbuzz](https://www.rootbuzz.com/)**  * **[Programlama](https://programlama.tk)**
>
> **Ruby**
>
> - **[openoverflow](https://github.com/nsanta/openoverflow)** (last commit in 2009)  *
>     **[T002_rails-overflow](https://github.com/membrain/T002_rails-overflow/)** (last commit in 2009)  * <s>**[SmartR](https://github.com/dkd/smartr/)**</s> Creator announced it is deprecated.  *
>     **[QARoR](http://github.com/mateuszdw/qaror)** (barely any progress)  * **[Discourse](http://www.discourse.org/)** (active, primarily a discussion forum)
>
> **Java**
>
> - **[AnswerHub](http://dzonesoftware.com/)**  * **[Confluence Questions](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/questions)**  *
>     **[Mamute](http://www.mamute.org/)**  * **[Scoold](https://live.scoold.com/)**
>
> **Scala**
>
> - **[Talkyard](https://www.talkyard.io)**
>
> **ASP.NET**
>
> - **[stacked](https://code.google.com/p/stacked/)**  *  <s>**[Stack Underflow](https://github.com/ripper234/Stack-Underflow/)**</s> No longer
>     supported.  * **[VolatileRead](http://volatileread.com/)**
>
> **MEAN (MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, and Node.js)**
>
> - **[PaizaQA](https://github.com/gi-no/paizaqa)**
>
> *Did I miss any? Disagree? Please add a comment or update this answer.*

My personal recommendation would be for [biostars.org](https://biostars.org).  To use the software you need to go at their "about" section, and there their public github repository is linked -- [github.com/ialbert/biostar-central](https://github.com/ialbert/biostar-central) -- with an install guide and all the information needed.

Comment: I had seen that.  It's rather overwhelming.  Could you pick the top three (or whatever number you choose) and give a brief description?  That would make your answer more useful.

Comment: @aparente001 I would vote for biostars, the second product seem good if you check their demo there, https://www.biostars.org/

Comment: What do you mean by "second product"?  The site looks very nice, but it seems to be about one specific topic.  I don't see how to use their software for a different project.

Comment: @aparente001 I mean the second link. To use the software you need to go at their about section, and there their public github reposetory is linked; https://github.com/ialbert/biostar-central, with the install guide and all the necessary information